# Matrix transformation, rotation around x axis

Tags: c#, matrix

I'm struggling my way through The Ray Tracer Challenge and have come to a test case in chapter 4 that I'm not able to get past.

```
Scenario: Rotating a point around the x axis
  Given p ← point(0, 1, 0)
    And half_quarter ← rotation_x(π / 4)
    And full_quarter ← rotation_x(π / 2)
  Then half_quarter * p = point(0, √2/2, √2/2)
    And full_quarter * p = point(0, 0, 1)
```

The first assert (half_quarter) works as expected, but the second (full_quarter) fails.

> Expected Matrix.Multiply(full_quarter, p) to be equal to (0, 0, 1, 1), but found (0, 6.12323399573677E-17, 1, 1).'

My implementation of `rotation_x` is as follows:

```
        public static double[,] rotation_x(double radians)
        {
            var cos = Math.Cos(radians);
            var sin = Math.Sin(radians);

            return new[,]
            {
                { 1,   0,    0, 0 },
                { 0, cos, -sin, 0 },
                { 0, sin,  cos, 0 },
                { 0,   0,    0, 1 }
            });
        }
```

Here's my multiplication method:

```
        public static double[] Multiply(double[,] a, (double x, double y, double z, double w) b)
        {
            var product = new double[4];

            for (var r = 0; r < 4; r++)
            {
                product[r] = a[r, 0] * b.x
                           + a[r, 1] * b.y
                           + a[r, 2] * b.z
                           + a[r, 3] * b.w
                           ;
            }

            return product;
        }
```

I have a lot of tests cases for matrices and vector multiplication from earlier chapters, so I'm pretty sure that part works as it should. But what else could be wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are passing in some value for π, but `Math.PI` is not exactly equal to π. It's approximately equal to π to within about 17 significant digits.

The sine of exactly π is exactly zero. **The sine of something very close to π is very close to zero**.  Which is what you got: 6 x 10<sup>-17</sup> is pretty close to zero.

Similarly, the cosine of π/2 is exactly zero, but the value of π/2 you are passing in is only accurate to 17 digits, so the result is only accurate to 17 digits.

Similarly, `Sqrt(2.0)/2.0` is not exactly √2/2. It's an approximation accurate to about 17 decimal places.

**Every** number in your system that is not an integer is correct to only within 17 decimal places, so there's no mystery here; your results are correct to within 17 decimal places because your inputs are correct to within 17 decimal places. You only get out as much precision as you put in.  Doubles are not infinite-precision!

(Nice use of tuple types, by the way -- but consider making structs to represent some of these concepts; that way you can put the methods associated with those concepts in the struct.)

Comment: Thanks! I like tulles, but it makes for some nasty method declarations....  I’ll consider structs, but I’m not sure how it will work out having methods work both on x,y,z and r,g,b tuples.

Comment: Precision was my first though, but 6-point-something is quite far from 0, so I discarded that idea. Just like I previously discarded all my knowledge about scientific notation of numbers....  I even wrote a method for comparing tuples with approximately- I just didn’t bother using it on this case since I was so far off... time to go to bed , I guess (almost midnight here in Norway)

Comment: @Vegar: To clarify your comment for those following along at home: you don't have six point something. You have 0.00000000000000006 something. **The E-17 means multiply by 10 to the negative 17**.